# How to apply a changelog file to packages in a PPA when building from recipe?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, packaging, deb, recipe

When my package gets build by launchpad using a recipe, it ignores the `./debian/changelog` file I provide, and it generates a useless one like following:

```
harmonyseq (0.14~natty1) maverick; urgency=low

  * Auto build.
 -- Rafal Cieslak <rafalcieslak256@gmail.com>   Tue, 25 Jan 2011 16:56:57 +0000
```

It would be much better if launchpad stored the list of changes I prepared in the changelog file, rather than just putting "Auto build" there.

How do I force launchpad to use the list of changes from my changelog file, when building packages from a recipe?

Comment: What are you using to trigger the builds? Under normal conditions, LP always uses the provided `debian/changelog`...

Comment: The best place to ask this question is Launchpad itself. Asking it there will allow the developers and experienced people to explain exactly how to do it, or why it can't be done

Launchpad has a special system to manage this type of questions, you can ask it [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad), where other people, including developers and users, will be able to answer you, or [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Feedback), where the thing becomes more official.

Comment: @KeesCook I can reproduce this. This **new** entry seems to get created when using a project.recipe to build the source file (locally via `bzr dailydeb project.recipe working-dir` where the recipe file just gets the source branch and nests the packaging information).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked this question on IRC (at #launchpad) and got the answer I was expecting:

No, it's not possible to prevent the creation of that changelog entry. It is necessary so that it can specify the appropriate autobuild version string (the one you define in the first line of the recipe file).

However, your changes should not be lost, just placed right after that entry.

Comment: Perhaps bzr-builder should integrate the autobuild changelog entry with any existing entry with the distribution set to UNRELEASED, as is common in debian changelog files.